# Unofficial meeting during house hunting trip

Tags: human-resources, meetings, first-job

I will start a new job in a month. I just came to the city yesterday (where I will work) for house-hunting, and I am staying at a hotel very close to my office location. I will be here for three days to look for an apt.

Do I need to inform my company that I am nearby? Such as emailing to HR and/or my future manager, and offer a lunch meeting?

I have mixed feelings about this, that is why I would like to know your opinions. Some friends suggested me doing it, as it would be kind. Also, my company may learn that I came nearby and didn't inform them. On the other hand, I am not ready to meet, as I am in my summer mood, with shorts, slippers and beard. I don't want to give a bad first impression on people whom I will work with.

Answer (score 13):

> Do I need to inform my company that I am nereby? Such as emailing to HR and/or my future manager, and offer a lunch meeting?

No, you don't need to meet anyone until you start and no real purpose would be served by doing so.

Answer (score 8):

Time is money, as we know.

What do you aim to get out of this meeting? Is there anything you want to discuss before starting? Anything that would be greatly helped by having a face to face conversation?

If yes, do it.

If no, avoid it.

Your future colleagues are busy working, you are busy house hunting. Wasting each other's time is surely not a good way to make a first impression.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to but it's a good idea to offer it.

I've done this multiple times and it was always a good experience. Once I managed to get a head start on a long lead time HR items. Once I had an informal lunch with some people from the new team. The whole thing may cost you and hour or two, but in my experience it can make your first day/week a lot smoother

If they say "no, thanks", you don't have to spent any time at all and you still make a good first impression as "collaborative & proactive".